# npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function (Windows)

Tags: reactjs

I'm having this problem when trying to install React, can anyone please help me?

```
C:\Users\MyName>npm install react --save
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v16.13.1
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mikok\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-08T13_47_27_192Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What version of npm are you using? Probably an outdated one? You should preferably use v7.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall NPM and install the latest version of Node. The current version, not LTS on the website.
2. Go to C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming and delete the "npm" and "npm cache" folders.
3. On your command prompt, run "npm cache clean --force".
4. Then run "npx create-react-app@latest your-app-name" or "npx create-next-app@latest your-app-name" depending on you preference.

> npm uninstall -g npm

or

> Uninstall Node from your program files.